# Is there a word that doesn't consist of any letters?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that doesn't contain any letters? More specifically, is it technically (or maybe grammatically) possible for a *word* to not contain any letters?

I should narrow the definition here. I'm considering anything in a highly regarded dictionary to be a word—nothing outside of one. Therefore something like a numeral isn't acceptable.

Comment: Define *word*.  There are at least a half-dozen reasonable sense here.

Comment: Yes. All English words contain no letters. They contain only sounds. Letters are only in writing, not language. Written English doesn't really represent English very well, which is why we get so many questions here.

Comment: @John I encourage you to create an answer out of that then. Sounds like an interesting point.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'd highly appreciate some more detailed thoughts on how and why written English doesn't really represent English very well.

Comment: Well, since you ask, [here's a selection.](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+orthography)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*24/7* is  itself a word. There are many sources backing this up. I find it incredible yet expected that this is possible. Hopefully I'm not late to the party and everyone already knows *24/7* is an actual word.

> **24/7** (*adverb*)
> Twenty-four hours a day, seven days a week; all the time
> *You just can’t afford to let things get you down, especially when you are on call 24/7.*
>
> <sub>[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/24/7)</sub>

Interestingly enough, this is a [numeronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym). Hopefully I'm not the only one who hasn't heard of this word either. The numerals are simply taking the place of *twenty-four seven*. Additionally, *24/7* is the only word I can find that makes use of any symbols other than letters and numerals.

Here's a definition of *word* to clarify how this can actually be a word:

> **word** (*noun*)
> 1.1 - A single distinct conceptual unit of language, comprising inflected and variant forms
>
> <sub>[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/word)</sub>

So *24/7* is definitely a concept expressing the consistency or continuity of something.

I should note that it's extremely rare for a word consisting of just numerals and symbols to appear in a highly regarded dictionary. Maybe I'm just crazy.

Comment: By that definition, every number symbol 0-9 is a non-alphabetic word.  Any non-alphabetic abbreviation, such as a unit symbol or a registered trademark identification would also qualify.  You're swimming in non-alphabetic words at that point...

Comment: @PaulGriffin You're forgetting the _comprising variant forms_ part. Lone numerals can't be altered in any way.

Comment: Oh, I've seen and used at least two different ways to write a 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, and an 8 before.  I don't mean to be contrary, I'm a bit interested in this.

Comment: @PaulGriffin "By that definition, every number symbol 0-9 is a non-alphabetic word.". Yup. "How many fingers am I holding up?" "3"

Comment: What is incredible and unexpected is that you say "Something like a numeral isn't acceptable" and then self-answer with a word comprising only numerals.

Comment: @AndrewLeach _A numeral_ meaning a standalone numeral. _24/7_ doesn't comprise only numerals. The backslash separator makes this two different numerals. In any case, I'm looking for dictionary entries and _24/7_ fits the bill.

Comment: 24/7 means nothing without knowing how it should be said. It looks like a fraction, prove to me it's not one, without context they are only numbers separated by a slash. 21/3 What does that mean? Well it's the first day of spring or if you're American it's 3/21.

Comment: @Mari Have a look at the definition above.

Comment: I know what the dictionary says those numbers represent. But prove to me it's not also a fraction.

Comment: @Mari I'm not here to prove your point. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophic_burden_of_proof) article. However, I agree it can be a fraction if you want it to, but my Q&A isn't discussing fractions.

Comment: 24/7 is meaningless without the explanation "twenty-four hours a day, seven days a week". It is shorthand, a abbreviation formed by numbers. Just like 3/21 can mean March twenty-first or the twenty-first day of March. **1728** what does that tell you?

Comment: And any other word is meaningless without explaining what is means. Sure, it could also stand for a date, but the point of this is that it appears in a respected dictionary, 3/21 doesn't.